# Defaultstringrepresentation in MDriven not showing

Tags: debugging, ocl, mdriven

Working on a timetracking database in MDriven. Trying to implement the different integers in a nicer way with strings but had some issues in "the New Debugger"

I have an instance with "Employee" having the attribute "Age" and would like it to be read "Employee is (*Insert age*) years old" like this default string representation:

```
'Employee is '+self.Age.asString+' years old'
```

but then, with MDriven's OCL in the new debugger

```
Employee.allinstances.asstring
```

does not correctly show the strings in "result as list". Why could this be?

For reference, I learned the basic differences between something like Visual Basic's string representation and MDriven's in this video:

https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Part_1_OCL_Common_Expressions

Comment: I have actually had the same problem and have also watched the tutorial videos on the MDriven Wiki which has worked well enough most of the time. In my instance I had a more complex string but  I'm certain that shouldn't be the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

What you expect is the correct behavior. There was a bug - a side effect  of cached ocl expressions - that explains the error result. This is fixed in builds after 2018-03-06